# Space between vertical scrollbar and content, but use the whole space when there is no scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Consider:

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-right: 10px; /* I want this only if scrollbar */
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">item1</div>
  <div class="item">item2</div>
  <div class="item">item3</div>
  <div class="item">item4</div>
  <div class="item">item5</div>
</div>
```

The right padding in `.container` is to add some space between the content and the vertical scrollbar. However, when the content does not overflow, there is no vertical scrollbar and I want the content to use the whole available horizonal space and so I do not want padding in that case. Can this be achieved with CSS?

Comment: As of my last knowledge cutoff, achieving this is not possible using only standard CSS.

Comment: This is not possible with css, you have to use javascript.
This might be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

I found the way by using calc() and css variables.
There are some a drawbacks. For example, the right padding now equeals scroll width then it is visible. But i believe that the hardest part is behind.

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  --widthA: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 80px;
  width: calc(var(--widthA));
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  --widthB: 100%;
  --widthC:  calc(var(--widthA) - var(--widthB));
  width: calc(var(--widthB) - var(--widthC ) );
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```